# Dynamic source for vue-i18n custom block

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm using  [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n)  and I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically change the source file of `<i18n>` to match the locale language.

For each vue component I have a folder with my different translations :

`├── myComponent
|   └── lang
|       ├── en.json
|       ├── fr.json
|   └── index.vue`

In my `index.vue` I'd like to do something like :

`<i18n src='./lang/' + $i18n.locale + '.json'></i18n>`

Is it possible ?

UPDATE:
So apparently it is not possible for now.

Comment: You can dynamically change the locale : http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html

Comment: Yes but thent I'd like to use this locale to use the corresponding file but when I run <i18n src='./lang/' + $i18n.locale + '.json'></i18n> I get the message `Cannot translate the value of keypath 'message.title'. Use the value of keypath as default.`

Comment: Is this now possible?